# Are comments posted on websites owned by the website or the commenter?

Tags: copyright, internet, intellectual-property

If a user comments on a website, and a third-party business owner uses text from that comment for commercial purposes, is that plagiarism or theft?

Answer (score 1):

It is not theft, since theft involves depriving the property owner of his thing, and the comment is still there where it originally was. However, stuff that a person writes can be protected by copyright law. You would have to look into the details of how the author used the website. The author may own the website and has simply posted comments for the world to see: any copying requires his permission. He may have posted text on someone else's website, and maybe the terms of use of that other website state that you agree to transfer your copyright to the website owner in consideration for permission to post a comment. That's basically what happens at SE, and most other public forums. In that case, it is, again, between the website owner (probably not the author) and the third party user (Mr. Businessman). The TOS may say "Anybody can copy anything here for any reason", or "Nobody can copy anything", or there may be some "non-commercial" condition attached to permission to copy. There is no general answer, except "Whatever the TOS says".

Plagiarism is not a legal concept. However, commercial / non-commercial is completely orthogonal to plagiarism, as is permission. Instead, plagiarism is all about (a) correct punctuation (things in quotes) and (b) proper attribution. If Smith copies a slogan from a website and uses it, passing it off as his own, then that is plagiarism. If he says that this slogan comes from someone else, it isn't. Plagiarism is about social sanctions, not law.

Comment: So if, let's say, YouTube's TOS says "All content is owned by us", and a business owner, let's say, uses a YouTube comment on his website, YouTube would have grounds to sue his business?

Comment: Yes, they would. But the person who made the comment would not - they already agreed that YouTube owns the comment.

Comment: Yes, although in fact their TOS doesn't say that, but *if* it did and they didn't grant permission to copy, then Mr. Business can be sued for infringement.

Comment: Most website terms grant the owner a licence: they generally do not transfer copyright

Comment: @JoeMorano The way such a thing would work is that you provide your content under a license. So while you *own* the content, you have granted YouTube certain rights under that license, such as the right to use your content for commercial purposes. You still own it, but YouTube can practically do what they wish with it.

Comment: @Zizouz212 But what about a third-party website who wants to use the comment for their own purposes?

Comment: @JoeMorano It still wouldn't make a difference. If you provide them with rights to your content, then you give them a licence. It's the same concept. The thing, is that *no one* will ever *own* your content. Copyright assignment, when you hand over ownership of your content, requires an agreement in writing. Clicking a few buttons over the internet doesn't do that :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 So you're saying that YouTube couldn't sue the third party, but the commenters could?

Comment: @JoeMorano Wait. Do you mean a third-party who comes to YouTube and pulls the user's content? In that case, the third-party wouldn't have rights to that content. IIRC, only YouTube has the right to use your content, and this is not shared with anyone else. Since YouTube doesn't own the content, they have no authority to file suit - only the owner, in this case the user, would be the only person able to sue.

Comment: @user6726 said "Plagiarism is not a legal concept", which is generally true, except (for instance) where used for fraud. If you're paid to create original works and you submit plagiarized work instead. That's fraud: a tort, a contract breach and possibly a criminal offense.